# Display the full country name rather than country code in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, country

Trying to use `<?php echo $current_user->billing_country; ?>` to display the WooCommerce user billing country. This for example echo’s as AU if the customer has an Australian billing address. However, I would like to pull the full name in place of the country code.

The same applies for the billing_state. Instead of getting South Australia I get SA. Have made work through functions.php, however only if I add each state and country. This is obviously a great undertaking to map the worlds states to the state codes.

I believe I have done this before in a very simple way, but for whatever reason cannot figure it out at this moment.

The country and state are being used within a disable input field as the value

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $current_user->billing_country; ?>" disabled="">
```

Image of what we currently get

[image: Image of what we currently get]

Image of what we want to get
[image: Image of what we want to get]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

WooCommerce has **`WC_Countries`** class for this you can use it like this:

```
echo WC()->countries->countries['AU']; //To get country name by code
echo WC()->countries->states['AU']['SA']; //to get State name by state code
```

OR (*in your case*)

```
echo WC()->countries->countries[$current_user->billing_country]; //To get country name by code
echo WC()->countries->states[$current_user->billing_country][$current_user->billing_state]; //to get State name by state code
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked a treat!

Comment: @DarrenMathers: don't forget to upvote my answer, as it helps you!

Comment: If the states have not been loaded, try `WC()->countries->get_states( $current_user->billing_country )[ $current_user->billing_state ]`.

Comment: this helped a lot. much obliged sire